# SSRS Report: List Control show data inside a table

Tags: reporting-services

I need to create an SSRS report in Visual Studio 2017 in which I need to show students information. Only the interest section of student should be shown inside a table

I have the following information.

STUDENT ID: 1234
NAME: ABC
CLASS : X A

INTEREST  | SINGING | DANCING | SPORTS | INSTRUMENTS

---

```
       | YES   |  NO      |   YES   | YES
```

STUDENT ID: 4321
NAME: XYZ
CLASS : X A

INTEREST  | SINGING | DANCING | SPORTS | INSTRUMENTS

---

```
       | NO   |  NO      |   YES   | NO
```

---

The above is a list control which shows each student details class info and interest info. Here the interests section should be shown inside a table.

Could you please tell me how to do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean the data should be displayed vertically as opposed to horizontally?

Comment: what do you mean by this  "Only the interest section of student should be shown inside a table"? ?Correct me if I'm wrong.. but you want for each student a single line with a yes or no against the column headings of  Singing, Dancing, Sports, Instruments?

Comment: In database, the table dbo.tblStudent looks like below                   
STUDENT ID | NAME | CLASS  | SINGING | DANCING | SPORTS | INSTRUMENTS
1234      ABC    X A       YES       NO        YES      YES                              But only the columns Singing to Instruments should appear as a table format

Comment: I can make the data horizontally in list, but that should look like a table

Comment: Can you post the schema of the table with the students Interests?